# Using a void type procedure to change a variable in C

Tags: c, procedure, void

I need to figure out how to use a void type function to change a value in another function, so I'm trying to write a practice program that uses a procedure to change an integer from 5 to 4 and then prints the new integer (should be 4).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void change(int x)
    {
    x = 4;
    }
int main(int argc, char **argv)
    {
    int z = 5;
    change(z);
    printf("%d\n",z);
    return 0;
    }
```

This prints 5 at the end. I can tell there's some kind of issue with scope here, but I can't figure out how to resolve it. I also can't print within the procedure, so that solution is out of the question. I'd really appreciate any help!

Comment: `void change(int *x){ *x = 4; }`, `change(&z);`

Comment: @Tetramputechture You seem to be misunderstood.

Answer (score 5):

To change a variable within another function, that isn't in the scope of the function, you must pass the variable by pointer.

```
void change(int *x)
    {
    *x = 4;
    }
```

And call the function using `change(&z)`.

If the variable isn't passed by pointer, then only the variable inside the scope of the function will change, but not its argument.

Answer (score 3):

In C, function arguments are always passed **by value**. This means that any changes made to a value in a function are **not** reflected in the caller. That is what's happening in your case.

Fortunately, you can pass a pointer (by value of course) instead. This allows you, via *dereferencing*, to change the value that the pointer is pointing to.

To do this, adjust the prototype of your function to

`void change(int* x)`

Then, within that function, use

`*x = 4;`

And, finally, call the function using

`change(&z);`

Answer (score 2):

You need to pass the address of the variable and then you can change the value of the variable.

```
void change(int *x)
{
    *x = 4;
}
```

Now the invoking function will have new value of x which is 4.

Answer (score -2):

You can pass a pointer to the function, like so:

void change(int *x)

Comment: ...and...the rest probably needs to be spelled out.

Comment: Does it? I have mixed feelings about providing code that someone can mindlessly copy without thinking about what it's actually doing.

Comment: Your answer, your choice.  What you've said is accurate; what you've not said is important to making your answer helpful — IMO.

Comment: My opinion is that, in the end, it's more helpful to provide something that is conducive to learning. From the positive votes you've just gotten  and the fact that you have over a 1/4 million reputation (and the negative vote that someone just gave me for my response), I wager that perhaps that's not the stackoverflow culture.

Comment: I'll take the other side of that wager with sure confidence that I'll profit from it.

Comment: Profit with... positive reputation? Is that the be-all and end-all on this site?